# Fastest way to browse journal papers (from Web of Science)?

Tags: research-process, software, reference-managers, library

The search engine which I typically use to browse journal papers is WebofScience. It allows me to sort by times cited, and check out who cited what.

The problem is that to get to the actual article once I have found one I am interested in takes many clicks and loading time: 1. Click FindIt button, 2. Click a link from my library access, 3. Click view full text. 4. Maybe save the article too, and import it into my reference manager.

i.e.

Step 1)

[image]

Step 2)

[image]

Step 3)

[image]

**Other options...**

Previously, my fastest process was to import the a list of selected references from WebofScience that I want to check out into EndNote by clicking the 'send to EndNote button', and then clicking find full text in EndNote to batch find the texts (works about 90% of the time, otherwise I had to manually click view PDF, save to my PC and then import).

Now I have discovered that Zotero can download a reference and the PDF with a single click from my browser, but only when I am searching on Elsevier or Scitation websites directly (but cannot select multiple articles for import at once, and means that I will usually have WebofScience open in a separate window to do the searching and then ctrl-c/v the article names across).

Is there an even faster way?

Comment: Do you use http://apps.webofknowledge.com/ ? When I use this, in the results list there is a button which takes me directly to the publisher and the article.

Comment: @Martin: yep that's what I use... maybe it is university dependent, but for me there is a number of intermediate steps before I can get to the article (updated above with screenshots)

Comment: Have you tried Google Scholar?  It often has direct links to PDFs in the search results.  But the fraction of papers for which it has the links varies a lot by field.  It's very high in fields that use the arXiv, for example.

Comment: @DavidKetcheson: Google Scholar is a good suggestion, but the problem is that it doesn't have sort by citation count or filter journal title?

Comment: It seems in fact to be dependend on the subscriber, sorry to hear that. I would not recommend google scholar for any deep research. Filtering and refining is very uncomfortable to use.

Comment: @James I believe Google Scholar always sorts by citation count.  It is the only tool I use to find research, because in my field Web of Science is completely missing a large portion of the literature, whereas GS is very complete.

Comment: @DavidKetcheson: Not quite. I am not sure how the "relevance" is calculated, but I often see higher cited articles further down on the list then they should be. However after using GS for a few days I think that it does deserve to be my primary research tool because of the speed and extra literature. Thanks again for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use Google scholar instead**

Advantages over Web of Science:

- Less clicks to access full text, or to save a citation
- More literature (including books) is available

Advanced search options (e.g. filter by Journal) can be accessed by clicking the arrow at the right hand side of the search box